# What is TCP6 773/cupsd ? why is it listening and why the ip is not cleared?

Tags: 12.04, networking

Hello everybody,
        Testing my open ports i ran command `sudo netstat -ntlup` with a normal looking output on my ubuntu 12.04 desktop.

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)

Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      PID/Program name

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:7634          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1919/hddtemp    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9393/dnsmasq    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      773/cupsd       
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      773/cupsd       
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                           9393/dnsmasq
```

But I can't see the port TCP6 773 is listening at i.e.

`tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      773/cupsd`

What is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tcp6` means an IPv6 address is being used, as evidenced by the `::1:631 :::*` listing. Also, it's a localhost connection as `::1` is the IPv6 address used for the `lo` network interface, similar to `127.0.0.1` on IPv4.

All of the addresses listed in your question, are only accessible via the `lo` interface, and not from the external Internet.